# Requiring or not a parameter

Tags: java, bnf, javacc, formal-languages

I'm using JavaCC on Java 8.

I have the following BNF form :

```
Program -> ( Definition )* EOF
Definition -> ( FUNCTION_DEF ) ( FUNCTION_NAME ) ( PARAMATER_NAME ) ( OPEN_B ) ( FUNCTION_BODY ) ( CLOSE_B )
```

With the following lexical analyser

```
TOKEN : { < EOL : "\n" | "\r" | "\r\n" > }
TOKEN : { < FUNCTION_DEF : "DEF" > }
TOKEN : { < FUNCTION_NAME : ( ["A"-"Z"] )+ > }
TOKEN : { < PARAMATER_NAME : ( ["a"-"z"] )+ > }
TOKEN : { < OPEN_B : "{" > }
TOKEN : { < CLOSE_B : "}" > }
TOKEN : { < SPACE : " " > }
```

As an input, I have the following :

```
DEF ABC x { x+1 }
DEF MAIN { ABC(1) }
```

My parser throws a parsing error because it requires a parameter name, obviously. How could I manage to require a parameter name ONLY if the function name is not MAIN?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may consider defining a separate expression for the `MAIN` function and then adding it to the definition of a program as an optional part:

```
Program -> ( MainDefinition )? ( Definition )* EOF
Definition -> ( FUNCTION_DEF ) ( FUNCTION_NAME ) ( PARAMATER_NAME ) ( OPEN_B ) ( FUNCTION_BODY ) ( CLOSE_B )
MainDefinition -> ( FUNCTION_DEF ) "MAIN" ( OPEN_B ) ( FUNCTION_BODY ) ( CLOSE_B )
```

**Edit**

To allow `MAIN` to be either at the beginning, at the end or in the middle of other functions' definition, you can just change the `Program` expression like this

```
Program -> ( Definition )* ( MainDefinition )? ( Definition )* EOF
```

Comment: Thanks! 
Now, how could I define a program to be either : a program where the main function is defined first, a program where the main function is defined at the end, a program where the main function is defined between the beginning and the end?

Answer (score 1):

You could make the parameter optional and report an error if the parameter is missing and the function name is not MAIN.

```
void definition() :
{
    Token t ;
}
{   <FUNCTION_DEF>
    t=<FUNCTION_NAME>
    (
        <PARAMETER_NAME>
    |
        {if( ! "MAIN".equals( t.image ) ) {
            throw new ParseException( "parameter name is required" ) ;
        }
    )
    "{"
    functionBody() ;
    "}"
}
```

---

You could also use semantic lookahead

```
void definition() :
{
    Token t ;
}
{   <FUNCTION_DEF>
    t=<FUNCTION_NAME>
    (
        LOOKAHEAD( { "MAIN".equals( t.image ) } ) 
        (<PARAMETER_NAME>)?
    |
        <PARAMETER_NAME>
    )
    "{"
    functionBody() ;
    "}"
}
```